# Python - Return Dictionary key based from input

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python just as a precaution. I am working on a project where I am storing a few different variables for different companies in a dictionary. I am trying to figure out how I can return a specific key from a specific dictionary. For example, user inputs their company name and the program returns a specific key from their specific companies dictionary.

I was able to successfully do this and print out the correct string but I now want to pass this value to the program that actually calling this code but nothing is being returned. I have attached a simple sample of the code I am using.

```
Company= "company1"

def getID():

    Companies = {
    "company1" :  {'ID_1': 'id3_12'},
    "company2" :  {'ID_1': 'id="id4_12"', 'ID_2': 'id5_12'},
    "company3" :  {'ID_1': 'id6_12', 'ID_2': 'id7_12'},
    "company4" :  {'ID_1': 'id8_12', 'ID_2': 'id9_12'}
    }


    id = (Companies[str(Company)]['ID_1'])
    return id
```

For example, someone will enter "Comany1" and python will return "id3_12"

I hope this makes sense!

Thanks all in advanced

Comment: Where are you calling the function from?

Comment: I am calling the function from an RPA application. I have troubleshot everything on their end. Just want to make sure this code should work before I bug them with my stupidity.

Comment: What I mean is how exactly are you calling it (the line of code)? Can you edit your post to include the function call? If it is from a different file, the folder structure would also be useful.

Comment: Your function doesn't take an argument, it only uses the gloabal variable `Company`. Did you meant to specifically do that?

Comment: @Talon That is exactly what I was missing!! I had that global variable in for testing. I removed that and added an argument for my variable to take and now we are working great. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not getting its data via an argument, but from the global variable `Company`. That won't work well if you're not in the global scope (which you should generally avoid), try this:

```
def getID(company):
    Companies = {
    "company1" :  {'ID_1': 'id3_12'},
    "company2" :  {'ID_1': 'id="id4_12"', 'ID_2': 'id5_12'},
    "company3" :  {'ID_1': 'id6_12', 'ID_2': 'id7_12'},
    "company4" :  {'ID_1': 'id8_12', 'ID_2': 'id9_12'}
    }
    id = Companies[str(company)]['ID_1']
    return id

print(getID("company1"))
```

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you!!